# send files and json data via post request in django

Tags: python, django

I have a django app in which i am uploading a file. After successful upload, I need to make a POST request to a web service and send along the file to that, along with JSON data, describing the file. Is there any library which can help me do that? I read about [Poster](http://atlee.ca/software/poster/) and [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/), but I could not determine how to send both types of data in the request.

Comment: Why not just send the uploaded file and json file together? http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#post-multiple-multipart-encoded-files

Comment: something like this: files = [('file':open('c:\\User\\myuser\\Documents\\mediaroot\\file.txt'), 'rb'), ('file2':data)]

Comment: You tell me :) Write a simple unit test that does the multi-file post. If it works, answer your own question with the results so others can learn from your experience.